# How to find the time complexity of this function?

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
def f1(n):
   cnt = 0
   for i in range(n):
      for j in range(n):
         k = 1
         while k < i*j:
            k *= 2
            cnt += 1
  return cnt
```

I am trying to analyze the time complexity of this function `f1`, I'm having some troubles dealing with the `k < i*j` in the loop. 
My point of view: 
I'm trying to find the number of iterations of the inner loop, so what I'm basically trying to find is when `2^k >= i*j`, but I'm having trouble dealing in how to compute `i*j` each time and find the overall time complexity. I know that at the end I will have `2^k >= n^2` which gives me `k >= log(n)` , but I must be missing all the iterations before this and I would be happy to know how to calculate them. 
Any help is really appreciated, Thanks in advance!
EDIT:
With Prune's help I reached this: We're trying to calculate how many times the inner loop iterates, which is `log(i*j)`. 
taking `i=2` we get `log(2) + log(j)` (n times) which is `n + log(1)+log(2)+...+log(n)`. 
So we have `n+log(n!)` for each `i=0,1,...,n` basically `n(n+log(n!))`. Which is either `O(n^2)` or `O(nlog(n!))`. as it's my first time meeting `log(n!)` I'm not sure which is considered to be the time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, let `m = i*j`.
As you've noted, you execute the `while` loop `log(m)` times.

The complexity figure you're missing is the summation:

```
sum([log(i*j)
        for j in range(n)
        for i in range(n)])
```

Would it help to attack this with actual numbers?  For instance, try one iteration of the outer loop, with i=2.  Also, we'll simplify the `log` expression:

```
sum([log(2) + log(j) for j in range(n)])
```

Using base 2 logs for convenience, and separating this, we have

```
n*1 + sum([log(j) for j in range(n)])
```

That's your start.  Now, you need to find a closed form for sum(log(j)), and then sum that for i = 0,n

Can you take it from there?

---

**After OP update**

The desired closed form for `sum(log(j))` is, indeed, `log(n!)`

This isn't simply "go `n` times`: it's the *sum* of log(i)*n + log(n!) over the range.

Comment: I think I got the idea, I will try to show you my calculations because I'm not really sure about it. first of all we are trying to find the whole sum of all iterations of "log(i*j)", to do that we split the log(i)+log(j) and took a number example of i. I guess the first iteration will be when i=2 would be (n+log(1)+log(2)+log(3)+...+log(n)) = (n+log(n!)). But thats just for a number example, so it should go n times so the whole sum would be : n*(n+log(n!)). so the time complexity would be O(n^2) or O(nlog(n!))?

Comment: Yes, you have the correct manipulation, up to a point.  Please add this to your question; it's hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and sorry for writing it in the comments like that, I didn't know what to click to write in code here, I edited my question explaining what I did, I really appreciate the help.